# C++ error with included headers

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, g++

I have problem with compiling C++ code on Linux operating system (LUbuntu 15.05).

Same code i compile on XUbuntu 14.10, Arch and Gentoo Linux. Everything is be fine. Now i install LUbuntu on home desktop pc and when i start make I give this error:

```
g++ -O2 -Wall -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/gthr-default.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from main.h:8,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/pthread.h:1058:55: error: ‘_lock’ was not declared in this scope
 extern int pthread_spin_trylock (pthread_spinlock_t *[_lock)
                                                       ^
/usr/include/pthread.h:1058:54: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘[’ token
 extern int pthread_spin_trylock (pthread_spinlock_t *[_lock)
                                                      ^
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

This is my main.h file:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_mixer.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#endif  // MAIN_H
```

I don't know what to do. I install build-essential.
Please help.

Comment: well, that is not c++ syntax. If you have access to the file, remove `[` from `(pthread_spinlock_t *[_lock)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked to that file in my system, and very near to line number 1058, there is this line:

```
extern int pthread_spin_trylock (pthread_spinlock_t *__lock)
```

Weird... your line has a `[` instead of the expected `_`...

If you look at the ascii values of `_` and `[`, they are:

```
_: 95 = 0x5F = 01011111
[: 91 = 0x5B = 01011011
```

See, just one bit of difference. Maybe your hard disk (sd-card?) was victim of a [cosmic ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray#Effect_on_electronics), but I'd do a full scan, of both the hard-disk and the memory, just in case.

And then, you should reinstall the relevant package, of course. I think it is `libc6-dev`, not `build-essential`, that is a dependency-only package, or whatever Debian calls it.